# Convert the date to UTC format

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have this date: 2014-08-14 16:00:00 which i retrieve it from the database by the code `$table_of_service->getDesiredDatetime()`, but i want to show this date to the user as this format  4-Nov-2014 04:00 PM and then calculate the UTC time for this time and show it to the user.

So how i will convert the date tho the format that i want and calculate the UTC time for the specific date in JQuery?

Note that the date value i recieve it in php and i must take it in JS.
in php this is the code:

$x = $concierge_service->getDesiredDatetime();

and in JS i must take the value of $x and store it in the JS variable to process its value
    var x =;

Comment: This question is all over the place. Learn about timezones. Why is this tagged JQuery and not PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var datetime = '2014-08-14 16:00:00';
            var split = [];
            split = datetime.split(" ");
            var convertedDateTime = Format(split[0]) + ' ' + tConvert(split[1]);

        });



        function Format(givenDate) {
            var mydate = new Date(givenDate);
            var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][mydate.getMonth()];
            var resultDate = ("0" + mydate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + month + '-' + mydate.getFullYear();

            return resultDate;
        }

        function tConvert(time) {
            // Check correct time format and split into components
            time = time.toString().match(/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

            if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
                time = time.slice(1);  // Remove full string match value
                time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
                time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
            }
            return time.join(''); // return adjusted time or original string
        }
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p3dxq8eb/)**